# Mongoose: foo.findById is no defined

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm trying to write a generic function to get Models by id in Express 4 using Node js 6.

```
module.exports.findModelById =  (model)=> {
  var Model = mongoose.model(model);
  const modelName = model.toLowerCase()
  return (req, res, next) => {
    Model.FindById(req.params[modelName + 'id']).exec((err, find) => {
      if (err) next(new Error('Error saving ' + modelName + ' .'))
      else {
        req[modelName] = find;
        next()
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I've required mongoose in my file, but as soon as i try to call it

```
findModelById('Foo')
```

i get

```
TypeError: Model.FindById is not a function
```

Thank you

Comment: [`findById`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) (lower case `f`).

Comment: it works ;) Thank you